# SQLiteOpenHelper won't fire onCreate

Tags: android

I am using this code

```
public class PeopleDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Person";
public static final String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.machinarius.labs.preloadedsql/databases/";
public static final String DB_NAME = "preload-test.sqlite";

private static final String DB_PREFS = "whyDoIHaveToDoThisAgain?";

private Context parent;

public PeopleDBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);

    parent = context;
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(DB_PREFS, 0);
    if(prefs.getBoolean("firstRun", true)) {
        prefs.edit().putBoolean("firstRun", false).commit();
        onCreate(null);
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onCreate()");
    InputStream source;
    OutputStream destination;
    byte[] buffer;

    try {
        source = parent.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        destination = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH + DB_NAME));
        buffer = new byte[512];

        while(source.read(buffer) > 0) {
            destination.write(buffer);
        }

        source.close();
        destination.flush();
        destination.close();
    } catch(IOException ex) {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "IOException", ex);
    }
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i2) {

    }
}
```

And i have been wondering... why do i have to implement that silly hack with SharedPreferences in order for onCreate to fire? Even after wiping application data from the Settings menu and calling getWritableDatabase() onCreate would not fire, leading to crashes coming from the persistence layer. What did i do wrong?

Comment: uninstall and reinstall the app from the device and check.

Comment: My guess is that onCreate is called only once when you first open the DB.  If you are testing your code, then, may be you can put the code in onUpgrade and keep changing the DB version so that onUpgrade gets called everytime you start debugging your app.

Comment: It would work, but it would not solve my problem as it would keep on resetting the DB, that's not what i want.